# yet another pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds (but with more debug)

Tags: python, git, emacs, rope, pymacs

I have followed [this guide](http://milkbox.net/note/installing-pymacs-rope-on-emacs-24/), and consulted these existing stackoverflow questions:

- [Pymacs helper did not start after 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254442/pymacs-helper-did-not-start-after-30-seconds)
- [Windows 8 + Emacs 24.3 + emacs-for-python: Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973236/windows-8-emacs-24-3-emacs-for-python-pymacs-helper-did-not-start-within-30)

But unfortunately, these did not solve my problem.  So, I've posted this question with more detail on my error.

Following the debug information emacs provides, I ran with --debug-init, and here are the results.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds")
  signal(error ("Pymacs helper did not start within 30 seconds"))
  pymacs-report-error("Pymacs helper did not start within %d seconds" 30)
  pymacs-start-services()
  pymacs-serve-until-reply("eval" (pymacs-print-for-apply (quote "pymacs_load_helper") (quote ("ropemacs" "rope-" nil))))
  pymacs-call("pymacs_load_helper" "ropemacs" "rope-" nil)
  pymacs-load("ropemacs" "rope-")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1936
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

My init.el is linked [here](https://gist.github.com/mittenchops/9785915).

I've installed rope, ropemacs, pymacs, etc., but am still getting this error.  I find further that pymacs seems to be unsuccessful in being imported in python in general:

```
>>> import Pymacs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pymacs
```

But this is bizarre, because:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/pinard/Pymacs.git 
$ sudo pip install -e Pymacs
```

installs successfully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, nevermind, I forgot to build the repo.

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```